# How to get sql code of VIEW in SQL server by programmatically in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

First, I can get base tables  and columns of a View by using simple way like these.

```
Private Function GetBasetableFromSql(ByVal viewTable As String) As Integer
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection
        sqlConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx_MMS;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx")
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim ta As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim strSql As String 
         strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT VIEW_NAME,c.TABLE_NAME " + _ 
                   FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS cu JOIN    
                   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c ON  c.TABLE_SCHEMA  = 
                   cu.TABLE_SCHEMA AND  c.TABLE_CATALOG = cu.TABLE_CATALOG AND     
                   c.TABLE_NAME    = cu.TABLE_NAME AND     c.COLUMN_NAME   = cu.COLUMN_NAME" & _
            " WHERE VIEW_NAME = '" & ViewTableName & "'"
        ta = New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, sqlConn)

        ta.Fill(dt)

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            dgvRootTable.Rows.Add(dr(0), dr(1))
        Next
        sqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return dt.Rows.Count
End Function
```

But some View was created by complicated query. So I need to get the sql code from a view before and use the way of regular expression (If there is another way.please tell me.)  for get table and column from string of sql code. 
But I have no idea how to get sql code by programmatically?

**Sameple** View which was created by sql code 
[image]

If I can get Base Table and Column.
I will create result in document like this

```
**View Table :** V_PO_SCRAP_NG_DTLS
[SCRAP_NG_DTLS].[TRAN_ID]
[SCRAP_NG_DTLS].[SEQ_NO]
[SCRAP_NG_DTLS].[CAUSE-OF-NG-JD]
[SCRAP_NG_DTLS].[CAUSE_OF_NG_DESCR]
[SCRAP_NG_DTLS].[NG_QTY]
```

Comment: Either it's a **view** or a **table** - what do you mean by *view table* ?!?!? A database object cannot be both at the same time .....

Comment: I means view. Sorry for my English. I mistake that  view may be adjective and table is noun . Thanks for make me understand.

Comment: why is this tagged with c#, vb.net and .net? this is a sql question.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the sql script of  view you can use following command . you could use same command to get sql script of stored procedure, and press Ctrl+T  to see the result in text format.

```
sp_helptext 'yourViewName or ProcedureName'
```